I can not access the environmental variable from Secret Manager that I passed in the secretEnv in Google Cloud Build
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        docker pull $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:latest || exit 0
    id: Pull docker cache
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-t'
      - $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - '-t'
      - $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:latest
      - .
      - --cache-from
      - $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:latest
    id: Build
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - run
      - '--rm'
      - $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - bash
      - '-c'
      - |
        export DEBUG=true
        echo
        env
        python manage.py test
    secretEnv: ['DJANGO_SECRET']
      - GCP_INFOS
    id: Test
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
    id: Push
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - '--platform=managed'
      - >-
        --image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
      - '--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION'
      - '--quiet'
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/DJANGO_SECRET/versions/latest
      env: "DJANGO_SECRET"


I tried to add this step just for testing purpose:
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim'
    entrypoint: bash
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        echo "Fetching DJANGO_SECRET from Secret Manager..."
        echo "$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="DJANGO_SECRET")"
    id: Get gcloud secrets for testing purpose

Here it correctly prints out the variable, which means that I correctly gave the permission to Cloud build and also the variable name is correct. However, with the above method it does not work, where I just provide the environmental variable as secretEnv
I gave both the Secret Manager viewer and Secret Manager admin (just in case) permissions to project_id@cloudbuild.developer.com, and also the environmental variable is availabe in the Secret manager.
It fails in the Test step, when I print env, it does not have the DJANGO_SECRET inside there. How to solve it?
I tried to check all the links, and did in the exact same way, but still not able to handle this.

Refer to this blog by Hossein Molavi which might be helpful for you.

Where do you expect your Env Var? In your docker run?

Yes, in docker run

You may need to grant the Secret Manager Secret Accessor, IAM role to access the secrets.
